# Smooth Streaming Player - Multi Audio Track - H.264 SmoothStreams

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, smooth-streaming, smooth-streaming-player

I am trying develop a silverlight player based on SmoothStreamingMediaElement.
For Ref:
SSME:SmoothStreamingMediaElement Grid.Row="2" x:Name="medSmooth" AutoPlay="True" MinWidth="320" MinHeight="240""

Now the Source Smooth Streams are encoded using H.264 video codec and AAC as Audio codec.
I found at below URL, that audiostreamindex and audiostreamcount properties are for WMV type only and that killed my only left hope.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.web.media.smoothstreaming.smoothstreamingmediaelement_properties(v=vs.90).aspx

Can any body help me on How I can detect the currently playing language in video, and then I want to put an event handler or "Users action of changing language", once that event i s fired, I want to change the currently playing audio track to the selected one.

Comment: BTW I was able to parse and find out the available list of language tracks available in source manifest file-

Comment: If S.Type = Windows.Media.MediaStreamType.Audio Then
                    ' languages.Add(count.ToString, S.Attributes("Name"))
                    'listLanguages.Add(S.Attributes("Name")
                    Language = New Language()
                    Language.LanguageId = count
                    Language.LanguageName = S.Attributes("Name").ToString
                    listLanguages.Add(Language)
                    count = count + 1
                End If

Comment: Basically I was hoping to create something like this -. http://player.smooth.vertigo.com/ , Try with source video as http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/o9/content/smf/smoothcontent/elephantsdream/Elephants_Dream_1024-h264-st-aac.ism/manifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use [Silverlight Media Framework](http://smf.codeplex.com), it really simplifies development of video applications. You can download its source code here: http://smf.codeplex.com/downloads/get/386528.

However, you can do some things without framework

- How I can detect the currently playing language in video

Here is the code:

```
var currentSegment = mediaElement.ManifestInfo.Segments[mediaElement.CurrentSegmentIndex.Value];
var currentAudioStream = currentSegment.SelectedStreams.Where(i => i.Type == MediaStreamType.Audio).FirstOrDefault()
```

- I want to change the currently playing audio track to the selected one

Something like this:

```
foreach (var segment in mediaElement.ManifestInfo.Segments)
{
    var newStreams = new List<StreamInfo>();
    // use current video streams
    var selectedVideoStreams = segment.SelectedStreams.Where(i => i.Type != MediaStreamType.Audio).ToList();
    newStreams.AddRange(selectedVideoStreams);
    // add a new audio stream
    newStreams.Add(newAudioStream);
    // replace old streams by new ones
    segment.SelectStreamsAsync(newStreams);
}
```

Comment: Cool! This method works for me, contrary to the solution with setting `AudioStreamIndex` property, described [here](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20-TECHS/SL1.html). Btw, `AudioStreamCount` always returns `1` for me, even if there are multiple audio streams.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [SMF](http://smf.codeplex.com/), here is the easiest solution:

```
private CustomPlayer SetAudioStreamLanguage(string languageCode)
{
    const string languageAttributeKey = "Language";

    if (AvailableAudioStreams.Count() < 2) return this;

    var languageCode = new CultureInfo(languageCode).ThreeLetterISOLanguageName();
    if (languageCode == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Audio stream language code {0} cannot be converted to three-letter ISO language code.", languageCode));
    }

    StreamMetadata newAudioStream =
        AvailableAudioStreams.FirstOrDefault(
            s =>
                s.Attributes.ContainsKey(languageAttributeKey) &&
                s.Attributes[languageAttributeKey].Equals(languageCode, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (newAudioStream == null) return this;

    SelectedAudioStream = newAudioStream;
    return this;
}
```

This method should be called after [MediaOpened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.mediaopened(v=vs.95).aspx) event has been fired.

NOTE: `CultureInfo.ThreeLetterISOLanguageName()` method does not exist in Silverlight. You can find it's sample implementation in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841106/parsing-culture-info-in-net/18228531#18228531).